# how to escape double quote characters in mysqli_query() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update the mysql database using a CSV file.

I have this Query working in phpmyadmin

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/website/test_mysql_import.csv' INTO TABLE `csv_preset` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

but when i try to use it within the mysqli_query function it does not update the database.

here's the full code block:

```
<?php require "db_connect.php"; ?>    
    <?php
    $csv_file = "C:/wamp/www/website/test_mysql_import.csv";

    $sql_dump ="TRUNCATE TABLE csv_preset";
    $sql_update = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv_file' INTO TABLE `csv_preset` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_dump);
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_update);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php require "db_connect.php"; ?>    
    <?php
    $csv_file = "C:/wamp/www/website/test_mysql_import.csv";

    $sql_dump ="TRUNCATE TABLE csv_preset";
    $sql_update = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$csv_file."' INTO TABLE `csv_preset` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_dump);
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_update);
?>
```

Comment: that worked @Macbernie thanks allot, I actually forgot to add a ; at the end of the $sql_dump query also, that was causing problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
        $sql_update = "LOAD DATA INFILE $csv_file INTO TABLE `csv_preset` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY &quot; ESCAPED BY &quot; LINES TERMINATED BY \\n";
```

There is no need for single quotes around your variable since it is already in double. Double quotes you can escape them with [htmlcode](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) and new line with the "\".